# Initials of first name in footcite

Tags: biblatex, citing

Is it possible to display initials of first name in footcite? I use `verbose-trad2` citestyle:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-trad2,bibstyle=authortitle-icomp,sortcites=true,%
    block=space,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
```

When i footcite first time it is ok:

> [First name initials] [last name], [title] ...

but in next citations of the same book it's only

> [last name], [title] ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a new name format `firstinits-last` (derived from `first-last` with `\iffirstinits` true), and point the `labelname` format (which is used in citations) to `firstinits-last`. (This also works if you don't set the `firstinits=true` package option; with this option enabled, you may simply add `\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{default}` to your preamble.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{firstinits-last}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{firstinits-last}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, Anton},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, Berta},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\textheight 160pt% just for the example

\begin{document}

Some text.\autocite{A01}

Some text.\autocite{B02}

Some text.\autocite{A01}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: work like a charm :)